# Should I diagram my usage of C++ standard library files/objects within my project?

Tags: c++, diagram, class-diagram, std

I'm just getting a start drawing diagrams of my senior university project and I'm wondering, should I include items from the C++ standard library?

For example, when making file dependency diagrams should I add every `#include` or just my files? Or, should I list items like `std::string` as being a dependency when used in the interface or implementation of one of my own classes?

I'm not sure what the best practices are for handling such common inclusions and I want to avoid clutter in my illustrations. I don't know if it will be of value to include standard library objects/files in my diagrams or if it'll be an annoyance with little to no benefit.

Comment: Which type of diagrams are you drawing? Is it schema based design or flow chart ?

Comment: Schematic in nature. A combination diagram of the physical structure of the software (file dependencies and component boundries) and the logical elements within each file and how they're all connected.

Comment: to design a diagram, you can use the Lucidchat https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/ It very easy to use as well as free. You don't need confused about best practice. It will handle smoothly and you should use their template category. thanks

Comment: I appreciate the software recommendation, but my concern isn't how to make a diagram, it's what I should or should not be including in my diagrams. What is it about the Lucidchart templates that addresses my question? For clarity, I'm creating diagrams in the style of those found in the book "Large Scale C++ Software Design" by John Lakos.

Comment: Does this help (I you replace "background classes" with "standard library classes")? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72576098/3723423