# Do background classes get represented in class diagram?

Tags: uml, diagram, class-diagram

In my android app , i have a lot background  classes. My question  is should i represent these classes  in classes  diagram

Comment: If you think they are useful then do. Else don't. Why would you think there's only a single diagram. Create as many as needed.

Answer (score 2):

It is a common mistake to think that there should be ***one*** class diagram with ***all*** the important classes of the system.

But this is not how it works. Each diagram is meant to convey the relevant information about a given topic. So you may very well have:

- a class diagram with none of your background classes because the do not add any useful information to your domain model.
- a class diagram with a couple of background classes, for example if you model say a GUI component and some background classes play an important role therein
- a class diagram with only a set of background classes, because it could be useful to document those (you probably have such a diagram if you use one of these popular frameworks that comes with a class diagram in its documentation.